# Match regex conditional

Tags: regex

I need help with a regex pattern.
It needs to capture the *last 5 digits* if the *5th digit from the end* is **1-9**,
if the *5th digit form the end* is a **0**, then it needs to capture the *last 4 digits*.

Samples

- `;135206701?` //should match `6701`
- `;135216701?` //should match `16701`
- `;135236701?` //should match `36701`
- `;135208701?` //should match `8701`

This is what i have so far, but it only correctly captures the items with *5 digits* (middle 2 samples)

```
(?<idnumber>(?!0)[0-9]{5})\?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?:[1-9]|(?<=0))\d{4}(?=\?$)
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/tJ5wO1/3)

The idea is:

- Either match a ***1-9*** digit (`[1-9]`) or (`|`) the existence of a ***0*** (`(?<=0)`)
- Followed by *four digits* `\d{4}`
- Followed by the existence of a *question mark* and the *end of the line* `(?=\?$)`

Comment: Nice answer. It could be `(?=\D*$)` to cover all bases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one:

```
([1-9][0-9]{0,4}|0)\?
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/aG4sI9/1)

Comment: Where did the idea of decremental matching come from? I don't get the vibe that it should be matching 3, 2, 1 and so on digits depending on where the last zero is.